# what is a "window descriptor" in tsql window function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

I'm currently learning tsql window function by following the book `tsql fundamental` by Ben Itzik.

In the section that explain what a `window` is in terms of window function, the author used the term `window descriptor`

[image]

Could someone please explain to me what `window descriptor` means and represents?

Comment: the `window descriptor` is basically the window function that you are going to use to evaluate the row to achieve what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "window descriptor" is the part that starts with `ROWS BETWEEN` or `RANGE BETWEEN`.

In many uses of window functions, this is implicit.  So:

```
select sum(x) over (order by y)
```

is really a shorthand for:

```
select sum(x) over (order by y rows between unbounded preceding and current row)
```

(or is that `range between` ;).

And:

```
select sum(x) over ()
```

is short-hand for:

```
select sum(x) over (rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following)
```

Answer (score 2):

As it is clearly written that a window function is a function that will operate on the basis of described formula or calculation from the over() clause and will give out the scalar result after processing every row of the selected window (rows set). So, **Window Descriptor** means it specifies how window rows should be selected in window function.